# Using string staged in Textbox in MapPath method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project to take data from a Word document and save it into an SQL database. I have everything working other than I currently have to hard code the path to where the image files have been stored (temporarily).

So this works:

```
using (Stream Image11 = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(@"\Temp\636794392003594492_files\image001.jpg")))
```

But I need to use something like this instead:

```
using (Stream Image11 = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("/" + Image1Up.ToString())))
```

unfortunately what I get when I try to use the value in the Image1up textbox is a string that ends with System.Web.UI.webcontrols.Textbox.

Comment: Use Image1Up.text to return the text value.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you RichardMc, that did it. Something simple that I should have seen, but a bit brain dead from fighting the overall project for days now.

```
using (Stream Image11 = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath("/" + Image1Up.Text)))
```